# How to make font bigger with html / css?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have this html:

```
 <div class="a"><font size="40"><font 
color="black">A</font></font></div>
```

The thing is, I can't make the font-size bigger. No matter what I do, it just stays at a certain size. If I increase `40` to `50`, for example, it makes no difference.

I then tried:

```
.a {font-size: 50px;}
```

Nothing.

Page ref: https://adsler.co.uk/about-adsler/

Comment: `<font>` is deprecated and should not be used, as many features (like `size=""`) don't work anymore. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font Use CSS as suggested by the other answers instead

Comment: @elveti font tag is obsolete, not deprecated. Sta, your font tag is overriding your class as it is inside and therefore takes precedence - remove the font tag and your css will work (and your html will be valid - at the moment it is not)

Comment: @Pete from MDN: "Do not use this element! Though once normalized in HTML 3.2, it was **deprecated** in HTML 4.01, at the same time as all elements related to styling only, then obsoleted in HTML5." same same

Comment: @elveti your point? - read the last part of your comment *then obsoleted in HTML5*.  obsolete has a completely different meaning to deprecated

Comment: @Pete ok dude, you win. `<font>` is obsolete

Comment: Here is what I have now. `<div class="a"> A </h1></div><div class="boutus"><bout Us</div>`..... `boutus {margin-left :100px; margin-top:180px; font-size: 90px; color: black;}`

Comment: But the text `bout Us` isn't showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of HTML5, the Font-tag is deprecated. Instead you should style all of your elements with css:

```
<div class="a"> A </div>

<style>
.a {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: black;
}
</style>
```

Comment: `.boutus {margin-left :100px; margin-top:180px; font-size: 90px; color: black;}`...`<div class="a"> A </h1></div><div class="boutus"><bout Us</div>` how come the text `bout Us` doesn't show?

Answer (score 2):

The `<font>` tag is no longer supported and does not work in HTML5.
Remove it and set the style in the `<style>` tag in the `<head>` or in the linked stylesheet:

```
<style>
 .a {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: black;
 }
</style>
```

Alternatively, set the style directly on the element inline:

```
<div style="font-size: 40px; color: black">A</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I already tried setting `font-size: 40;` Does it work only if I remove the html font size?

Comment: Yes, remove the <font> tags. See this codepen for the correct implementation. If the styles are not updating, try setting the styles inline on the div, shown in the second example: https://codepen.io/Roughton/pen/vwOgNR

Comment: So here is what I have now: 
`.boutus {margin-left :100px; margin-top:180px; font-size: 90px; color: black;}`.....`<div class="a"> A </h1></div><div class="boutus"><bout Us</div>`

Comment: If what you have typed is correctly copied from your web page then there are a few typos: there is a space after margin-left and before the colon, there is a closing </h1> tag after the text but no opening <h1>. I recommend trying to replicate your styles in a codepen because I cannot diagnose the problem based on the copied text alone.

Answer (score 1):

You should use CSS style for `div` tag :-

```
    <div style="font-size:50px; color: black;">A</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

font tag supports "size" attribute to be a number between 1 to 7
you could use the custom css on font tag with "style" attribute like

```
<font style="font-size:40px;">A</font>
```

or you could remove the font tag and apply the style attribute to div tag

```
<div style="font-size:40px;">A</div>
```